# How to rewrite find function of nested lists using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a `List<Unicorn>`, with each unicorn containing a `List<Rider>`, return the unicorn and the latest rider info for a subset of riders.

I've written this as such:

```
static Optional<ImmutablePair<Unicorn, Rider>> findLatestExperiencedRiderInfo(
        final List<Unicorn> unicorns) {

    Rider latestExperiencedRider = null;
    Unicorn unicornOfLatestExperiencedRider = null;
    long latestRideTime = 0L;

    for (final Unicorn unicorn : unicorns) {
        for (final Rider rider : unicorn.getRiders()) {
            if (rider.getType() == Rider.Type.EXPERIENCED) {
                final long time = rider.getRideTime();
                if (time > latestRideTime) {
                    latestRideTime = time;
                    latestExperiencedRider = rider;
                    unicornOfLatestExperiencedRider = unicorn;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return latestExperiencedRider == null
            ? Optional.empty()
            : Optional.of(new ImmutablePair<>(
                    unicornOfLatestExperiencedRider,
                    latestExperiencedRider));
}
```

I was hoping for a more succinct version, possibly using streams (or just written differently). What would be your suggestions?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is my suggestion.

Comment: Please post [mcve] including stripped down versions of `Unicorn` and `Rider` and some test data so a proposed answer can be tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a stream version

```
unicorns.stream()
        .flatMap(unicorn -> unicorn.getRiders()
                .stream()
                .filter(rider -> rider.getType() == Rider.Type.EXPERIENCED)
                .map(rider -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(unicorn, rider)))
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(entry -> entry.getValue().getRideTime()))
        .map(entry -> new ImmutablePair<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

The `flatMap` part flattens all the Riders into `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`s each containing a `Rider` and the `Unicorn` it was part of. Then we get the max entry by comparing two `Rider`'s `rideTime`. If present, we create the ImmutablePair result else will be `Optional.empty`

Comment: +1 for the `SimpleEntry<>(unicorn, rider)`  way of doing it..that's what came to my mind looking at the return type as well

Comment: Although it's a minor change. using `comparingLong` would be ideal here.

Comment: @Aomine Functionally there will be no difference as `Long.compareTo` calls `Long.compare`. But even I feel it is better and hence edited it. Thanks

Comment: @user7 that's not my point. using `comparingLong` one avoids boxing/unboxing overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, you can add the required null checks..

```
// This is your rider..
final Optional<Rider> aRider = unicorns.stream()
                                       .flatMap(unicorn -> unicorn.getRiders().stream())
                                       .filter(rider -> rider.type == Rider.Type.EXPERIENCED)
                                       .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Rider::getRideTime));

 // This is your unicorn..
final Optional<Unicorn> any = unicorns.stream()
                                      .filter(unicorn -> unicorn.getRiders().contains(aRider.get()))
                                      .findAny();
```

You can also keep a reference to a `Unicorn` in the `Rider` I guess so you do not need to search your unicorn once you have your a rider.

Comment: was thinking of a similar idea..., anyway I think you should be using `max` instead of `min` and consider using `Comparator.comparingLong` as opposed to `Comparator.comparing` in this specific case.

Comment: @Aomine Maybe we can put a `distinct` and `unordered` after `flatMap` in the first statement.. I am not very experienced with Unicorns :) Yes, you are right thanks for your comments, will fix now. I read `latest` as `least`..